# MVC 4 Entity Framework 4 POCO: Schema specified is not valid

Tags: frameworks, schema, entity, asp.net-mvc-4

These are my errors that I can't seem to fix:

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
The relationship 'Repository.ForumCategory' was not loaded because the type 'RepositoryModel.ForumCategories' is not available.
```

This is my ForumCategory class:

```
public class ForumCategory
{
    //
    // Scalar Properties
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Order { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Forum> Forums { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Forum class:

```
public class Forum
{
    //
    // Scalar Properties
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string Icon { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int ThreadCount { get; set; }

    public int PostCount { get; set; }

    public virtual Nullable<DateTime> LastPostDate { get; set; }

    public int Order { get; set; }

    //
    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual ForumCategory Category { get; set; }
}
```

This is my RepositoryContext:

```
public class RepositoryContext : ObjectContext
{
    private IObjectSet<ForumCategory> _forumCategories;
    private IObjectSet<Forum> _forums;

    public SHRepositoryContext()
        : base("name=Repository", "Repository")
    {
        ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        _forumCategories = CreateObjectSet<ForumCategory>();
        _forums = CreateObjectSet<Forum>();
    }
    public IObjectSet<ForumCategory> ForumCategories
    {
        get { return _forumCategories; }
    }

    public IObjectSet<Forum> Forums
    {
        get { return _forums; }
    }
}
```

This is my entity model: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/txkED.png]

Really need help, have read a few answers from people but none seem to be relevant =\

Comment: I have fixed my own question hehe!

The problem was:
I had an association overriding my name of the ForumCategory in the model.

The solution was:
I renamed the association to Forum_Category and renamed the entity to ForumCategory.

This fixed my issues!

Comment: The common practice is to post your own answer as answer and accept it (to mark question as resolved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was: I had an association overriding my name of the ForumCategory in the model. The solution was: I renamed the association to Forum_Category and renamed the entity to ForumCategory. This fixed my issues!